# Graph plotting using system of ODE with NDSolve command

Tags: boundary-conditions

In the present question, I am trying to solve a system of ODEs with corresponding boundary conditions. And then, trying to plot the velocity function, but it shows some errors. Can anyone please help me rectify the error and help in plotting the graph? Actually, previously the code was working fine, but I want to tinker with some values, so now it stops working and Shows "1/5.33164*10^307 is too small to represent as a normalized machine 
number; precision may be lost." this error. If anyone needs any further information, please let me know.. Thanking for your time and consideration in advance.

Constant numerical values

```
\[Beta] = 0.01;
\[Epsilon] = 0.1;
\[Alpha] = 1;
\[Zeta] = 0;
H = 1;
M = 1;
k = 1.5;
t = Pi/3;
z = 0.5*\[Pi];
\[Rho]2 = 997.1;
\[Mu]2 = 0.001004;
\[Sigma]2 = 5.5*10^-6;
\[Rho]1 = 783;
\[Mu]1 = 0.00151;
\[Sigma]1 = 5*10^-11;
\[Sigma] = \[Sigma]1/\[Sigma]2
\[Mu] = \[Mu]1/\[Mu]2
\[Rho] = \[Rho]1/\[Rho]2
M1 = Sqrt[\[Mu]/\[Sigma]]*M
H1 = Sqrt[\[Mu]/\[Rho]]*H
```

System of Equations

```
eq = {(u100''[
       y] + (1/(y + k)*u100'[y]) - (1/(y + k)^2*u100[y])) - (M^2*
      u100[y]) + (k/(y + k)*H^2) == 
   0, (u110''[
       y] + (1/(y + k)*u110'[y]) - (1/(y + k)^2*u110[y])) - ((M^2 + 
        I*H^2)*u110[y]) + (k/(y + k)*H^2) == 
   0, (u200''[
       y] + (1/(y + k)*u200'[y]) - (1/(y + k)^2*u200[y])) - (M1^2*
      u200[y]) + (k/(y + k)*\[Rho]*H1^2) == 
   0, (u210''[
       y] + (1/(y + k)*u210'[y]) - (1/(y + k)^2*u210[y])) - ((M1^2 + 
        I*H1^2)*u210[y]) + (k/(y + k)*\[Rho]*H1^2) == 
   0, (f1''[y] + (1/(y + k)*f1'[y])) - (f1[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + \[Alpha]^2) + M^2)) == 0,
  (f2''[y] + (1/(y + k)*f2'[y])) - (f2[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + \[Alpha]^2) + M^2)) == 
   0, (f3''[y] + (1/(y + k)*f3'[y])) - (f3[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + \[Alpha]^2) + (M^2 + (I*H^2)))) == 
   0, (f4''[y] + (1/(y + k)*f4'[y])) - (f4[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + \[Alpha]^2) + (M^2 + (I*H^2)))) == 
   0, (f5''[y] + (1/(y + k)*f5'[y])) - (f5[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + \[Alpha]^2) + M1^2)) == 
   0, (f6''[y] + (1/(y + k)*f6'[y])) - (f6[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + \[Alpha]^2) + M1^2)) == 
   0, (f7''[y] + (1/(y + k)*f7'[y])) - (f7[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + \[Alpha]^2) + (M1^2 + (I*H1^2)))) == 
   0, (f8''[y] + (1/(y + k)*f8'[y])) - (f8[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + \[Alpha]^2) + (M1^2 + (I*H1^2)))) == 
   0, (g1''[y] + (1/(y + k)*g1'[y])) - (g1[y]*(1/(y + k)^2 + M^2)) == 
   0, (g2''[y] + (1/(y + k)*g2'[y])) - (g2[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + (4*\[Alpha]^2)) + M^2)) == 
   0, (g3''[y] + (1/(y + k)*g3'[y])) - (g3[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + 4*\[Alpha]^2) + M^2)) == 
   0, (g4''[y] + (1/(y + k)*g4'[y])) - (g4[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2) + (M^2 + (I*H^2)))) == 
   0, (g5''[y] + (1/(y + k)*g5'[y])) - (g5[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + 4*\[Alpha]^2) + (M^2 + (I*H^2)))) == 
   0, (g6''[y] + (1/(y + k)*g6'[y])) - (g6[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + 4*\[Alpha]^2) + (M^2 + (I*H^2)))) == 
   0, (g7''[y] + (1/(y + k)*g7'[y])) - (g7[y]*(1/(y + k)^2 + M1^2)) ==
    0, (g8''[y] + (1/(y + k)*g8'[y])) - (g8[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + (4*\[Alpha]^2)) + M1^2)) == 
   0, (g9''[y] + (1/(y + k)*g9'[y])) - (g9[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + (4*\[Alpha]^2)) + M1^2)) == 
   0, (g10''[y] + (1/(y + k)*g10'[y])) - (g10[
       y]*(1/(y + k)^2 + (M1^2 + (I*H1^2)))) == 
   0, (g11''[y] + (1/(y + k)*g11'[y])) - (g11[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + (4*\[Alpha]^2)) + (M1^2 + (I*H1^2)))) == 
   0, (g12''[y] + (1/(y + k)*g12'[y])) - (g12[
       y]*((1/(y + k)^2 + (4*\[Alpha]^2)) + (M1^2 + (I*H1^2)))) == 0}
```

Boundary conditions

```
bc = {u100[1] == 0, u110[1] == 0, u200[-1] == 0, u210[-1] == 0, 
  f2[1] == 0, f4[1] == 0, f1[1] == -u100'[1], f3[1] == -u110'[1], 
  f5[-1] == -(Cos[\[Zeta]]*u200'[-1]), 
  f6[-1] == -(Sin[\[Zeta]]*u200'[-1]),
  f7[-1] == -(Cos[\[Zeta]]*u210'[-1]), 
  f8[-1] == -(Sin[\[Zeta]]*u210'[-1]), 
  g1[1] == -(1/4*u100''[1]) - (1/2*f1'[1]), g2[1] == -(1/2*f2'[1]), 
  g3[1] == (1/4*u100''[1]) + (1/2*f1'[1]), 
  g4[1] == -(1/4*u110''[1]) - (1/2*f3'[1]), g5[1] == -(1/2*f4'[1]), 
  g6[1] == (1/4*u110''[1]) + (1/2*f3'[1]),
  g7[-1] == -(Cos[\[Zeta]]/2*f5'[-1]) - (1/4*
      u200''[-1]) - (Sin[\[Zeta]]/2*f6'[-1]), 
  g8[-1] == -(Sin[\[Zeta]]/2*f5'[-1]) - (Sin[2*\[Zeta]]/4*
      u200''[-1]) - (Cos[\[Zeta]]/2*f6'[-1]), 
  g9[-1] == (Cos[\[Zeta]]/2*f5'[-1]) + (Cos[2*\[Zeta]]/4*
      u200''[-1]) - (Sin[\[Zeta]]/2*f6'[-1]), 
  g10[-1] == -(Cos[\[Zeta]]/2*f7'[-1]) - (1/4*
      u210''[-1]) - (Sin[\[Zeta]]/2*f8'[-1]), 
  g11[-1] == -(Sin[\[Zeta]]/2*f7'[-1]) - (Sin[2*\[Zeta]]/4*
      u210''[-1]) - (Cos[\[Zeta]]/2*f8'[-1]), 
  g12[-1] == (Cos[\[Zeta]]/2*f7'[-1]) +(Cos[2*\[Zeta]]/4*
      u210''[-1]) -(Sin[\[Zeta]]/2*f8'[-1]), u100[0] == u200[0], 
  u110[0] == 
   u210[0], (\[Mu])*(u100'[0] -u100[0]/k) == (u200'[0] -u200[0]/
     k), (\[Mu])*(u110'[0] -u110[0]/k) == (u210'[0] -u210[0]/k), 
  f1[0] == f5[0], f2[0] == f6[0], f3[0] == f7[0], 
  f4[0] == 
   f8[0], (\[Mu])*(f1'[0] -f1[0]/k) == (f5'[0] -f5[0]/
     k), (\[Mu])*(f2'[0] -f2[0]/k) == (f6'[0] -f6[0]/
     k), (\[Mu])*(f3'[0] -f3[0]/k) == (f7'[0] -f7[0]/
     k), (\[Mu])*(f4'[0] -f4[0]/k) == (f8'[0] -f8[0]/k), 
  g1[0] == g7[0], g2[0] == g8[0], g3[0] == g9[0], g4[0] == g10[0], 
  g5[0] == g11[0], 
  g6[0] == 
   g12[0], (\[Mu])*(g1'[0] -g1[0]/k) == (g7'[0] -g7[0]/
     k), (\[Mu])*(g2'[0] -g2[0]/k) == (g8'[0] -g8[0]/
     k), (\[Mu])*(g3'[0] -g3[0]/k) == (g9'[0] - g9[0]/
     k), (\[Mu])*(g4'[0] -g4[0]/k) == (g10'[0] -g10'[0]/
     k), (\[Mu])*(g5'[0] -g5[0]/k) == (g11'[0] -g11[0]/
     k), (\[Mu])*(g6'[0] -g6[0]/k) == (g12'[0] -g12[0]/k)}
```

Variables

```
var = {u100, u110, u200, u210, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, g1, g2,
    g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, g10, g11, g12};
```

Technique opted

```
coord = {y, -1, 1}; op = 
 Method -> {"Shooting", 
   "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}};
var0 = Table[var[[i]]@y, {i, Length[var]}];
var1 = D[var0, y];
var2 = D[var1, y];
sol0 = Solve[eq, var2];
sol01 = sol0 /. y -> 1;
sol02 = sol0 /. y -> -1;
bc1 = bc /. sol01[[1]] /. sol02[[1]];
sol = NDSolve[{eq, bc1}, var, coord, op];
With[{n1 = sol[[1]]}, 
  u101[y_] := (f1[y]*Sin[\[Alpha]*z] + f2[y]*Cos[\[Alpha]*z]) /. n1;
  u111[y_] := (f3[y]*Sin[\[Alpha]*z] + f4[y]*Cos[\[Alpha]*z]) /. n1;
  u201[y_] := (f5[y]*Sin[\[Alpha]*z] + f6[y]*Cos[\[Alpha]*z]) /. n1;
  u211[y_] := (f7[y]*Sin[\[Alpha]*z] + f8[y]*Cos[\[Alpha]*z]) /. n1;
  u102[y_] := (g1[y] + g2[y]*Sin[2*\[Alpha]*z] + 
      g3[y]*Cos[2*\[Alpha]*z]) /. n1;
  u112[y_] := (g4[y] + g5[y]*Sin[2*\[Alpha]*z] + 
      g6[y]*Cos[2*\[Alpha]*z]) /. n1;
  u202[y_] := (g7[y] + g8[y]*Sin[2*\[Alpha]*z] + 
      g9[y]*Cos[2*\[Alpha]*z]) /. n1;
  u212[y_] := (g10[y] + g11[y]*Sin[2*\[Alpha]*z] + 
      g12[y]*Cos[2*\[Alpha]*z]) /. n1;
  u10[y_] := (u100[y] + \[Epsilon]*u101[y] + \[Epsilon]^2*u102[y]) /. 
    n1;
  u11[y_] := (u110[y] + \[Epsilon]*u111[y] + \[Epsilon]^2*u112[y]) /. 
    n1;
  u20[y_] := (u200[y] + \[Epsilon]*u201[y] + \[Epsilon]^2*u202[y]) /. 
    n1;
  u21[y_] := (u210[y] + \[Epsilon]*u211[y] + \[Epsilon]^2*u212[y]) /. 
    n1];
```

Plot command

```
p1 = Plot[
  Piecewise[{{Re[(u20[y] + (\[Beta]*(E^(I*t))*u21[y]))], -1 <= y <= 
      0}, {Re[(u10[y] + (\[Beta]*(E^(I*t))*u11[y]))], 
     0 <= y <= 1.2}}], {y, -1, 1.1}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{Style[
       "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(H\), \(Water\)]\)=0.3", Bold, 
       12]}], {0.2, 0.2}], PlotStyle -> {Cyan}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["\[Eta]", Black, 13, Bold], 
    Style["U", Black, 13, Bold]}, 
  LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[{Black, 15}, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times new Roman"]]
```

Comment: @AlexTrounev sir, can you please help me in this?

Comment: Did you read my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287175/plotting-of-graph-after-solving-system-of-odes-using-ndsolve-command/287206#287206 ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes sir

Comment: @AlexTrounev sir can you please help me rectifying, my error in this code

Comment: Is my answer correct? If so why not to upvote it?

Comment: Yes, it was correct @AlexTrounev; I don't have any problem upvoting it. I don't know that every time we have to upvote it. Okay, I think it is regarding some points or reputations. Okay, I will do it now sir.

Comment: Thank you. In your current code parameter  `M1^2=165438` is too large for shooting method, it is why we have  messages from `NDSolve`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Moreover it is also showing this one, The equations derived from the boundary conditions are numerically \
ill-conditioned. The boundary conditions may not be sufficient to \
uniquely define a solution. If a solution is computed, it may match \
the boundary conditions poorly

Comment: Use `M1 = Sqrt[\[Mu]/\[Sigma]]*M/100;` and analyze picture. Is it what you expected?

Comment: @AlexTrounev okay sir, I will check